# GridView Column show/hide onclick of checkbox causing gridview paging problems

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm invoking showhide() function from checkbox onclick event, this showhide function is also hiding the Gridview pages because gridview pager also formed with `<tr>` and `<td>` and in my code I'm using index of grid view column to hide. But for my requirement I only have to hide the gridview columns. Is there way to do this?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkReceiveDt" runat="server" Checked="true"
              OnClick="showhide(this,'ReceiveDt')" />

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function showhide(sender, ColumnText) {
      var isChecked = $('#' + sender.id).is(":checked");
      var th = $("[id*=GridView1] th:contains(" + ColumnText + ")");
      th.css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
      $("[id*=GridView1] tr").each(function () {
        $(this).find("td").eq(th.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
      });

    }

  </script>
```

Comment: The only way I can think of is copying all the contents from row `<tr class="pager">` into a dummy table.

Comment: @VDWWD Gridview pager happens dynamically so i have no control on it to copy the tr element to dummy table.

Answer (score 0):

On Checkbox click event pass the column number of Gridview that you want to hide/show to function below. Code works very well and does not interfere with paging of Gridview.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkReceiveDt" runat="server" Checked="true"
                  OnClick="showhideColumn(this,1)" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function showhideColumn(sender, col_num)
        {
            var isChecked = $('#' + sender.id).is(":checked");
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID %>");
        for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
            grid.rows[i].cells[col_num].style.display = isChecked ? "" : "none";
        }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today as well when following [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Hide-ASPNet-GridView-Columns-on-CheckBox-Checked-Unchecked-using-jQuery.aspx) authors tutorial. Thought I would also share my simple fix for fixing issues with pager.

Since the pager is stored in the thead and tfoot, we could just ignore those when selecting the rows from the gridview by simply adding the following line when selecting our rows:

```
.not('thead tr').not('tfoot tr');
```

So

```
$("[id*=GridView1] tr").each(function () {
        $(this).find("td").eq(th.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
      });
```

Becomes

```
$("[id*=GridView1] tr").not('thead tr').not('tfoot tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find("td").eq(th.index()).css("display", isChecked ? "" : "none");
      });
```

And no more pagination problems. Now depending on how your GridView paginates, you may run into problems with maintaining column visibility accross PostBacks. To solve this, I save and read isChecked from a hidden field, and `OnRowDataBound` of the GridView I [Register a Client Script Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.110).aspx) to adjust the view.